# How to remove the last slash from the url with params in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to remove the trailing slash after domain from the url with params in wordpress.
For example:
http://example.com/?param=1 -> http://example.com?param=1

Comment: Remove how? Through `htaccess`? Inside a string in code?

Comment: We cannot help you with this little information. Please add more detail.

Comment: Please share more details. Where do you print that URL? Why not modify it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trim command to do this, specifically, the rtrim to remove the character from the right side:

```
$url = rtrim(get_permalink(),'/');
```

Using a blanket `substr -1` technique would cause problems if there isn't a trailing slash in the permalink. Also, the function `the_permalink` echoes the link, and `get_permalink` returns it as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to redirect to the url after removing last slash. How can I do it?